# What does MSE mean in the calculation of separation reliability for rasch model?

Tags: reliability, item-response-theory, rasch

In the Rasch model, the reliability of separation can be calculated as 1 - (MSE / SD^2), where SD represents the standard deviation of person location measures on a logit scale, and MSE refers to the mean squared errors of item location measures.

What confused me is how to compute MSE and what it signifies. Is there a specific example or code?